# What's fastest way to re-test iPhone core data migration to a new version?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, xcode4, migration

What's fastest way to re-test iPhone core data migration to a new version?

That is, how would one set up an easy/quick way to:

- set up older version of app on simulator
- run the new version of the app from Xcode which will as part of running it on the simulator effectively run the migration

BACKGROUND- haven't had to do a migration yet. It's not to me in Xcode how to do the first bullet in particular.  Would one use a previous image/snapshot as part of the approach?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What I always did is:

1. navigate to your applications folder `/Users/username/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/` notice the iOS version number, its the one you're using in the simulator
2. there should be one or more folders with hash values, found the one you're working with
3. in the documents folder should be your `.sqlite` database file (as long as you haven't changed the directory in code)
4. backup that one (for example version 1)
5. when you want to test the migration, simply replace this db file with your backup

(the hash may change when you delete and rebuild your app)

Comment: thanks iPortable - can I clarify: (a) is there any need to have other aspects of the app in place to properly test a migration, or is just the database enough? i.e. is state self-contained in the single SQLite file then?  (b) is there a way to clarify/confirm which build in the directory you mention would link to the v1 release I would have down a week or so ago?  or would it be just based on timestamp?  (c) I can't see a sqlite file in the v1 release binary I created, so worst case I'd have to run this again and then grab the sqlite file from the app after it runs I guess?

Comment: a) actually it is enough to replace the database because thats the situation when your clients update the app from the appstore. On there devices the database file will remain (probably a migration) and the app itself is updated. b) you can delete all apps and built v1 again then you know it, or use the MacApp Base (theres a free demo in the web) to open the sqlite file. c) the database will not be packed to the binary. It will be created on the device. Here you can use the application PhoneDisk to search on your phone filesystem (even without a jailbreak)